# How should I implement my Drum Machine App?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a drum machine using Reactjs. It is working good but I have some performance issue and I also want to add a audio changing interface. Currently, the app have to initialize an Audio object every time the user clicks a drum pad(too bad!!!) and I tried to add another feature of changing audio but I couldn't.. I am new to Reactjs so any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="drumBox">
        <h2 className="drumHeader">Drum Machine</h2>
        <input type="button" value="Q" onClick={() => play(Q)} />
        <input type="button" value="W" onClick={() => play(W)} />
        <input type="button" value="E" onClick={() => play(E)} />
        <input type="button" value="A" onClick={() => play(A)} />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="S" onClick={() => play(S)} />
        <input type="button" value="D" onClick={() => play(D)} />
        <input type="button" value="Z" onClick={() => play(Z)} />
        <input type="button" value="X" onClick={() => play(X)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const play = e => {
  var snd = new Audio(e);
  return snd.play();
};

export default App;
```

I am calling a **play** function on clicking each drum pad. As you can see, the audio object **snd** is initialized on each click. How should I fix this and be able to change volume?

Comment: snd should be a property of App

Comment: @PhilippSander and then how should I use that property?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which JavaScript audio library you are using so I can't test fully this working. Also, I am not sure if you are trying to do it in Angular or not.

However, I can show you how to do it with jQuery assuming that Audio is available.

Change your HTML to:

```js
$(".drum").on('click', function(){
      let note = $(this).val();
      try{
              new Audio(note);
      }catch(e){
          console.log("Couldn't play note: ".concat(note)); 
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="main">
    <div className="drumBox">
      <h2 className="drumHeader">Drum Machine</h2>
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="Q" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="W" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="E" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="A" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="S" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="D" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="Z" />
      <input class="drum" type="button" value="X" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe by making each pad input a component with is Audio :

```
const PadInput = ({value})=>{

  const a = new Audio(value)
  const play = ()=>{
    a.play();
  }

  return (
    <input type="button" value={value} onClick={play} />
  )
}
```

and using it like this :

```
<PadInput value="A"/>
```

or for only one Audio this can probably work :

```
class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    audio : new Audio()
  }

  play = (sound)=>{

    const {audio} = this.state;
    audio.src = sound;
    audio.play();
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PadInput label="A" sound={A} play={this.play}/>
      </div>
      );

  }

}

const PadInput = ({label, sound, play})=>(
  <input type="button" value={label} onClick={()=>play(sound)} />
)
```